# regarding, considering, concerning, in terms of, etc. - interchangeable?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

I'm pretty confused about the usage of these linking words. Is there a difference in meaning? Are they all correct in this context? Which ones are more/less commonly used?

*What aspects **regarding** the fashion industry have changed over time?*

*What aspects **concerning** the fashion industry have changed over time?*

*What aspects **considering** the fashion industry have changed over time?*

*What aspects **with regards to** the fashion industry have changed over time?*

*What aspects **about** the fashion industry have changed over time?*

*What aspects **in terms of** the fashion industry have changed over time?*

*What aspects **related to** the fashion industry have changed over time?*

*What aspects **in relation to** the fashion industry have changed over time?*

*What aspects **connected with** the fashion industry have changed over time?*

*What aspects **in connection with** the fashion industry have changed over time?*

Comment: Define *interchangeable*. Interchangeable in what contexts? Primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All these expressions are  synonymous with each other without much difference in meaning.

> **[regarding](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/regarding)** (preposition)
>
> **Synonyms**: *concerning, as regards, with regard to, in regard to, with respect to, in respect of, with reference to, relating to,
>   respecting, as for, as to, re, about, apropos, on the subject of, in
>   connection with*

**Usage note**:

> Although sometimes considered poor substitutes for **about** or
>   **concerning**, the phrases ***as regards, in regard to, and with regard to*** are standard and occur in all varieties of spoken and
>   written English, especially in business writing: *As regards your
>   letter of January 19.* …**Note** that although ***in regards to*** and
>   **with regards to** are generally considered poor usage, these less formal variants have become increasingly common.

As per the Ngram viewer, **'about'** is the most commonly used preposition among these.

[image]

Comment: In connection to your answer, there are two fundamental aspects regarding *about* that you omitted to mention: i) *about* is far more informal than any of the other linking expressions listed by the OP. ii) It is very rare to start a sentence with *about*.

Comment: You also need to cite your source, although a link is welcome, that link may rot over time, and users will not know where this information came from.